# How to get result after post in curl

Tags: php, curl, post, https

I have this curl code, I want to print the result but is showing blank page

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/verify",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       "secret=0800000000",
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


print_r($response);
```

Please I need help.

Comment: If $response is blank, whatever configuration you used returned blank, review the configuration

Comment: the above configuration is the one I used

Comment: check your response code, if it is 404 , everything is working as expected in your script

Comment: response is blank

Comment: `secret=0800000000` doesn't look like an HTTP header - you'd normally expect a format like `Secret: 0800000000`. Have you checked the value of the error? It won't do anything if you just store it in a variable.

Comment: I first tried Secret: 0800000000 but it didn't work

Comment: the error also blank